# Algorithmic construction of a loop

Tags: algebraic-topology, algorithms, simplicial-complex

Let $X$ be a finite simplicial complex such that its geometric realisation $|X|$ is homeomorphic to a closed, connected, orientable manifold $M^n$. Suppose we are given an element $\gamma \in \pi_1(|X|)$ (where we know the fundamental group from abstract, non-implemented reasons).

My Question: Is there a sort of algorithm that allows us to construct a  representative of this homotopy class (maybe even as a simplicial embedding)?

I do not know how to think about this problem. I think that an analogous statement for (simplicial) homology works if one supposes that the Hurewicz homomorphism is surjective and the dimension is high enough (i.e., we want to find an embedding $\partial \Delta^2 \hookrightarrow |X|$ that represents a given homology class, where we know that a suitable embedding exists in $M$ via abstract reasons): Then one can just write down every simplicial embedding of $\partial \Delta^2$ into the complex (maybe iteratively subdivide), which is possible since all complexes involved are finite. Since (simplicial) homology can be computed algorithmically, one can check if the result is the desired class and by the abstract existence of a suitable embedding, this algorithm terminates.

However, these techniques do not seem to work for homotopy groups since they can be not computed algorithmically (or at least I do not know how it could be done). Any help, literature or helpful thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you do not even know what the generators of your "abstract" group correspond to in terms of the complex $X$, then there is nothing you can do. You have to have a better information relating your "abstract" group and the combinatorics of $X$.

Comment: One key difference of fundamental and homology groups is that thevword problem for finitely presented groupsvis undecidable.

Comment: Here's a rough idea: View $|X|$ as a CW-complex, find a maximal spanning tree of the 1-skeleton and contract it. Then you obtain $$\pi_1(|X|) \cong \langle e_1^1, \ldots e_n^1 \mid \text{ 2-cell boundaries}\rangle$$ with generators the remaining 1-cells, and computing the 2-cell boundaries should not be too difficult with proper bookkeeping, since you started with a simplicial complex. Now you need to only match this back to $G$, but (a) there will generally be multiple ways to do so and (b) more gravely perhaps this invokes the word problem (?)

Comment: Also, on a different note: There _are_ algorithms for computing homotopy groups of (nice) finite simplicial complexes, but the "nice" here universally seems to include "simply connected." Also these algorithms all have terrible complexity and not of great use for practical applications except perhaps in very low dimensions (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: What do these words mean? Namely, *we know the fundamental group from abstract, non-implemented reasons*. I ask because you have to start from *something*. For example, if Joe Schlobotnick comes up to you and informs you, from his lofty, abstract, non-implemented perspective, that the fundamental group is nontrivial, I'm not sure that information in and of itself is sufficient to construct any single loop that is homotopically nontrivial.

Comment: Thank you all! I already thought that it may be not really doable in this general setting. My complex arises as a simplicial connected sum of two other simplices (in high dimension), hence I "know" the fundamental is the free product of the two fundamental groups before. I will try to understand the two simplices with their $\pi_1$'s (which will be doable I think) and then I can maybe construct the desired loops with this info. Again thank you all for your input!